# 'Failed to finalize LSBundleWrapper' on SwiftUI app build for release

Tags: ios, macos, swiftui, apple-m1

I have a new app which I'm building to be cross platform using SwiftUI

When I build for release I get a very odd error in a popup generated by Xcode.

```sh
Unable To Install ‚Äúnomadgo.ProductivityDashboard‚Äù

Please try again later.
Failed to finalize LSBundleWrapper mutator instance for
```

[image]

I only get this error one I build for release. I tried restarting my Macbook.

Specs:

Xcode Version 12.5.1 (12E507)
MacBook Air (M1, 2020) BigSur

The app is fresh project using all latest Xcode settings for cross platform SwiftUI.

I get the error when trying to run the app on my MacBook.[image]

Answer (score 24, accepted):

I had exactly same issue. In my case deleting the project from `Containers` folder and cleaning the project in Xcode (`⌘ + ⇧ + K`) helped.

Comment: just clean is enough

Comment: Where do I find that "Containers" folder?

Comment: Thanks to @m-karolczyk! Another way: XCode / Product / Clean Build Folder

Comment: Clean isn't sufficient to resolve this on an M1 Ultra Mac Studio. Rebooted, blew away DerivedData, issue still persists. However, the same project on an M1 Pro MacBook Pro doesn't have the issue.

Comment: @Anticro command line `find "$HOME/Library" -name "*YourAppName*" 2> /dev/null` in the Terminal will locate any Container folder(s) and other related locations.

Answer (score 3):

Just in case, if you are still in this issue even after cleaning builds, check the Xcode `Settings…` > `Locations` > `Derived Data` path. The *Derived Data path* should be somewhere in your *macOS boot drive*.

Xcode 14.2 (14C18), Mac OS 12.5

---

In this "Failed to finalize LSBundleWrapper" scenario, the ProductName.app is not completely built. This case can be verified by checking the hidden product build folder "…/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/.XCInstall". The most significant missing piece is the lack of an executable:

```bash
Debug-iphoneos$ tree -a
.
└── .XCInstall
    └── ProductName.app
        ├── WrappedBundle -> Wrapper/ProductName.app
        └── Wrapper
            ├── BundleMetadata.plist
            └── ProductName.app
                ├── Icon.png
                ├── Info.plist
                └── PlaceholderEntitlements.plist
```

Xcode 14.3.1 (14E300c), Mac OS 13.4

Comment: That was my problem as well. As I tend to have DerivedData on an external drive or a RAMDisk, this is a severe regression for me. Please join me in reporting a feedback.

Comment: I have my build stuff in a RAM Disk, as well. And it also never worked for me. To me this seems to be a proper solution (I have upvoted it). But I simply can't understand why Apple does a mayhem like that...